# Animation Nodes: Problem with script node

Tags: python, scripting, animation-nodes

When I enter a simple opperation in the text part of the script node it doesn't work. The result doesn't change like you see in my pictures. However I try to follow instructions from tutorials.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I don't understand that what I did wrong.?

Comment: Should be `result = float * 34`, most likely.

Comment: Omg ! Shame on me ! Thank you !